# How do I navigate from listview.builder to a local PDF assets on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to turn a church Sunday school book into an app and I created a list of the book chapters with titles using the `listview.builder` widget. I have tried using the ontap property with `navigator.push` to redirect to a new page displaying a local PDF assets file, but it has not worked.

Comment: The ontap with naviagtor.push actually worked with displaying each item's chapter title but I don't know how to get it to display my PDF files for each list items..help please

Comment: Please check the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You should share your code with us and be as clear as possible abour your issue.